# Помогите составить sql запрос на получение записей с использованием связующей таблицы

Tags: sql

Есть 2 таблицы.

Таблица `post`: (id, title, description)

Таблица `post_for_users`: (id, user_id, post_id)

В `post` хранятся некие посты, в `post_for_users` связи с id пользователей.

Нужно получить все записи из таблицы `post`, если id пользователя присутствует в связанной таблице `post_for_user`. Всё казалось бы очень просто, вот только если у поста из `post` нет ни одной записи в `post_for_user` - этот пост также нужно выводить в итоговой выборке.

То есть запись выводится если у поста нет связанных записей в `post_for_user`, или если есть запись с конкретным, заранее известным user_id

Не силён в сложных sql запросах и пробую как-то так (конечно получаю не тот результат который нужно):

`SELECT * FROM post LEFT JOIN post_for_user ON post.id = post_for_user.post_id WHERE post_for_user.user_id = {ID ПОЛЬЗОВАТЕЛЯ} OR COUNT(post_for_user) = 0`

Comment: Условие `post_for_user.user_id = {ID ПОЛЬЗОВАТЕЛЯ}` перенесите в ON, а where вообще уберите. Того же эффекта можно было бы добиться если `count(post_for_user)=0` заменить на `post_for_user IS NULL`. потому что если записи нет в связанной таблице, то ее поле равно именно NULL и поэтому обычное сравнение с id такие записи подавляет. А count() вообще использовать в where нельзя

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте Union: объедините два запроса - посты с фильтрацией по пользователю и посты без пользователей.

Как-то так:

```
SELECT p.* 
FROM post p 
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT * 
               FROM post_for_user pu 
               WHERE pu.post_id = p.Id 
                 AND pu.user_Id = {ID ПОЛЬЗОВАТЕЛЯ} )
UNION
SELECT p.* 
FROM post p 
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * 
                   FROM post_for_user pu 
                   WHERE pu.post_id = p.Id )
```

Comment: А нафига выбирать поля в WHERE EXISTS? да ещё и ВСЕ? Хватит какого-нибудь SELECT 1 FROM ... ну и UNION ALL куда как разумнее.

Comment: А вы проверьте будет ли разница между SELECT 1 и SELECT *
Насчёт UNION ALL в целом согласен, разумнее, но главное не забыть что могут быть дубликаты потом, когда в запрос изменится и множества возвращаемых частями данных станут пересекаться. Поэтому предложил UNION, т.к. он безопаснее.

Comment: *проверьте будет ли разница между `SELECT` 1 и `SELECT *`* Зависит от СУБД, наверное... на MySQL есть, во всяком случае по расходу памяти, тестил когда-то на какой-то из пятых версий.

Answer (score 2):

Задача не ясна, но решение наверное такое:

```
with post as (
  select 1 as ID, 'title1' as TITLE, 'descr1' as DESCRIPTION from dual union all
  select 2 as ID, 'title2' as TITLE, 'descr2' as DESCRIPTION from dual union all
  select 3 as ID, 'title3' as TITLE, 'descr3' as DESCRIPTION from dual
)
  , post_for_users as (
  select 1 as ID, 1 as USER_ID, 1 as POST_ID from dual union all
  select 2 as ID, 2 as USER_ID, 2 as POST_ID from dual
)
/*
select *
from post
  left join post_for_users pfu on post.id = pfu.post_id
where pfu.user_id = :P1 or pfu.user_id is Null
*/
/*
select *
from post, post_for_users pfu
where post.id = pfu.post_id(+)
  and (pfu.user_id = :P1 or pfu.user_id is Null)
*/
```